# Testing a build of jQuery

Tags: jquery, qunit

How can I run the qUnit tests shipped with jQuery. I don't understand why there are PHP files, for example here https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/test/data.

Is there some sort of script that will run all the tests?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are full usage examples in [the documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/QUnit); I found them by googling `jquery test` and going to the first result.

> To use QUnit, you have to include its qunit.js and qunit.css files and provide a basic HTML structure for displaying the test results *[code follows]*.

[jquery/test/index.html](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/test/index.html) already appears to perform full coverage of the jQuery tests.

Comment: I was looking for `jquery/test/index.html`, thanks. Essentially I thought I had to manually open every `.html` file. And BTW, I'm not that lazy.